# Consequences of 'VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode'

Tags: solidity, web3js, exceptions

## The question

Hello everyone, could anyone explain to me the consequences of:
`VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode.`

## The context

I'm passing in an integer in web3js that is not mapped to an enum in my solidity contract - I have 2 elements in the enum and I'm intentionally passing in an index of 2, expecting the transaction to fail. The transaction does fail , however I expected a revert and not an invalid opcode. Should I handle parameter sanitisaton in some way?

Comment: It appears to be a decision made by solidity developers https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3027

Comment: Thanks for the input, however this link only explains the semantics and not the consequences of the exception